# angular code not displaying data asynchronously

Tags: angular

Through (app.component.ts), I'm trying to get data from a service (mydb.service.ts) that displays after a delay of 10 seconds, and displays through the (aap.component.html) template.

**mydb.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Restaurant } from './restaurant';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MydbService {

  private dbUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api';  // URL to web api

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }

  viewall(): Observable<Restaurant[]> {
    // This code below delays return for 10 seconds (to simulate real life delays)
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while ((new Date().getTime() - start) < 10000) {
      n: 1;
    }
    console.log('10 secs over');
    return this.http.get<Restaurant[]>(this.dbUrl+'/view');
  }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Restaurant } from './restaurant';
import { MydbService } from './mydb.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'myangular';
  restaurants$: Restaurant[];

  constructor(private dbService: MydbService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.viewrestaurants();
  }

  viewrestaurants(): void {
    this.dbService.viewall()
      .subscribe((restaurants) => {
        this.restaurants$ = restaurants;
        console.log(restaurants);
      });
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
test<br>
<li *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants$">{{restaurant.restaurantName}}</li>
```

According to my logic, `test` is supposed to be displayed initially without any delay, and after 10 seconds the `<li>` items are to be displayed.However, on starting Angular the complete data in (app.component.**html**) displays only after 10 seconds. How to display the `<li>` items asynchronously?

Comment: try to add async pipe of angular here <li *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants$ | async">{{restaurant.restaurantName}}</li>

Comment: when i use async i get the following error: ERROR Error: "InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the way Browser handles parsing of HTML and Javascript, if there is a javascript operation needed to be done then the browser will wait for the script to finish the script then create the DOM, then the render tree and then a reflow and paint will happen on your screen.

The problem with your code is, you are making it too intensive on the CPU just so that you can wait for 10 seconds sybchronously for it to display the view.

Modify your method like below:

```
viewall(): Observable<Restaurant[]> {
    return this.http.get<Restaurant[]>(this.dbUrl+'/view').pipe(delay(10000));
}
```

Comment: debounceTime doesn't seem to cause any delay. after ```test``` is displayed the ````<li>```` populate immediately.

Comment: @user3980196 I have probably misunderstood `debonceTime` then, use `delay` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an observable directly in the markup you need to use the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) eg. `<li *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants$ | async">{{restaurant.restaurantName}}</li>`

Another option is to let the component handle the observable by using a public variable. Then you set that variable when the observable respons. By this method you can do `<li *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants">{{restaurant.restaurantName}}</li>`

Comment: when i use async i get the following error: ````ERROR Error: "InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'"````. on letting the component handle the observable, there seems to be no delay.

Comment: sorry. Normally the `$` suffix indicates an observable. I thought `restaurants$` was a reference to an observable of a behaviourSubject. Does your `viewAll` method return that observable? your component seems fine.

Comment: actually **http** method in viewall() is supposed to return an observable (of an array). the api returns a json object. i'm a bit confused as well.